# Implement menu/options button in fullscreen custom view Android

Tags: android, menu, android-custom-view, android-fullscreen

I have a fullscreen Android app which I created in the days of Android 2.2 when phones still had hardware menu buttons. I am in the process of updating it to be compatible with Android 6. Unfortunately, most new users can no longer access the settings and options menu because new phones simply do not have the hardware menu button anymore.

How can I implement an onscreen button which takes the user to the settings or options menus in a fullscreen app? I do not want to have to resort to using a title bar with the options drawer.

My game view is a custom view coded in an xml layout file. I have already searched the internet and Google's own Android documents and there seems to be no documented way of doing this. Maybe I'm missing something.